# SOAP API with AES Encryption in Jmeter

Tags: soap, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, ase

I am going to do load test on SOAP API and involves operations like AES Encryption. Can we perform the load test by using Jmeter. If yes, How we can overcome issue. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Your question is too general; We need more information, like "overcome issue"? What issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jmeter-wssecurity](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity) plugin for signing/encrypting messages using various AES algorithm implementations

1. Install `WS Security for SOAP` plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]
2. Once you do this and restart JMeter you should be able to add `SOAP Message Encrypter` pre-processor and specify desired encryption settings there like algorithm, which message parts to encrypt, whether to encrypt attachments, etc.

   [image]

More information: [Running SOAP WS-Security Load Tests in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-soap-ws-security-load-tests-in-jmeter)

Comment: Sure, will try in this way. Thanks for the response